ansible change value of fact while looping through
I have a custom fact that is a list of dictionaries. I need to look at the value of each dictionary item and potentially change some of the values. below is an example of the fact, my loop looks at each item and queries an api for information related to bt_device and potentially change the value
[
    {
        "at_device": "sw",
        "at_name": "GigabitEthernet0/5",
        "at_type": "dcim.interface",
        "bt_device": "sw2",
        "bt_name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/2",
        "bt_type": "dcim.interface"
    },
    {
        "at_device": "sw",
        "at_name": "GigabitEthernet0/8",
        "at_type": "dcim.interface",
        "bt_device": "sw3",
        "bt_name": "GigabitEthernet1/0/5",
        "bt_type": "dcim.interface"
    }
]

so based on the query I need to change "sw3" to "fp3"
the below tasks work to show the data I want to change to on the screen, but I cannot make the leap to modifying the value in the fact as needed.
- name: load custom fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    custom_fact: "{{ custom_fact | default([]) + [{ 'at_device' : ansible_net_hostname, 'at_name' : item.key, 'at_type' : 'dcim.interface', 'bt_device' : item.value[0].host, 'bt_name' : item.value[0].port, 'bt_type' : 'dcim.interface'}] }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts | dict2items }}"

- name: modify custom fact via query
  debug:
    msg: "{{ query(NetBoxy stuff).device.name }}"
  when: "query(NetBoxy stuff) | length > 0"
  loop: "{{ custom_fact }}"

Thanks
I have attempted many things however I am new enough to have no idea how to get there.

Q: Change "sw3" to "fp3".
A: The solution depends on the structure of the data. For example, given the dictionary
  update:
    key: bt_device
    regex: sw3
    replace: fp3

the declaration below
  result: "{{ devices | rejectattr(update.key, 'regex', update.regex) +
              devices | selectattr(update.key, 'regex', update.regex) |
                        zip([{update.key: update.replace}]) |
                        map('combine') }}"

gives what you want
  result:
  - at_device: sw
    at_name: GigabitEthernet0/5
    at_type: dcim.interface
    bt_device: sw2
    bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
    bt_type: dcim.interface
  - at_device: sw
    at_name: GigabitEthernet0/8
    at_type: dcim.interface
    bt_device: fp3
    bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/5
    bt_type: dcim.interface



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    devices:
      - at_device: sw
        at_name: GigabitEthernet0/5
        at_type: dcim.interface
        bt_device: sw2
        bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
        bt_type: dcim.interface
      - at_device: sw
        at_name: GigabitEthernet0/8
        at_type: dcim.interface
        bt_device: sw3
        bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/5
        bt_type: dcim.interface

    update:
      key: bt_device
      regex: sw3
      replace: fp3

    result: "{{ devices | rejectattr(update.key, 'regex', update.regex) +
                devices | selectattr(update.key, 'regex', update.regex) |
                          zip([{update.key: update.replace}]) |
                          map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result



The next option is a simpler dictionary that allows updating of more keys. For example,
  update:
    bt_device: {regex: sw3, replace: fp3}
    at_device: {regex: sw, replace: swX}

the declarations below
  devices_updated: |
    {% for device in devices %}
    { {% for k in  device.keys()|intersect(update) %}
    {% if device[k] == update[k]['regex'] %}
    {{ k }}: {{ update[k]['replace'] }}, {% endif %}{% endfor %} }
    {% endfor %}
  result: "{{ devices |
              zip(devices_updated.splitlines()|map('from_yaml')) |
              map('combine') }}"

gives
  result:
  - at_device: swX
    at_name: GigabitEthernet0/5
    at_type: dcim.interface
    bt_device: sw2
    bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
    bt_type: dcim.interface
  - at_device: swX
    at_name: GigabitEthernet0/8
    at_type: dcim.interface
    bt_device: fp3
    bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/5
    bt_type: dcim.interface



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    devices:
      - at_device: sw
        at_name: GigabitEthernet0/5
        at_type: dcim.interface
        bt_device: sw2
        bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/2
        bt_type: dcim.interface
      - at_device: sw
        at_name: GigabitEthernet0/8
        at_type: dcim.interface
        bt_device: sw3
        bt_name: GigabitEthernet1/0/5
        bt_type: dcim.interface

    update:
      bt_device: {regex: sw3, replace: fp3}
      at_device: {regex: sw, replace: swX}

    devices_updated: |
      {% for device in devices %}
      { {% for k in  device.keys()|intersect(update) %}
      {% if device[k] == update[k]['regex'] %}
      {{ k }}: {{ update[k]['replace'] }}, {% endif %}{% endfor %} }
      {% endfor %}
    result: "{{ devices |
                zip(devices_updated.splitlines()|map('from_yaml')) |
                map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: devices_updated
    - debug:
        var: result



Thank you for the detailed response, I have a few clarifying questions:


is it possible in this example to modify the original list items or must the changes be saved to a new list?


can the modifications be made while looping through the original list? the reason for this would be when there are keys with the same value in multiple list items but we only want to modify certain items, so say in your example we only want to change 'at_device' to 'swX' on the second item in the list without affecting the first.



in the last 'devices_updated' I see we are looping through the dictionary, what I do not know is what the comma is for after '{{ k }}: {{ update[k]['replace'] }}'. also I believe if I can add another assignment to this true if statement to modify one of the other key values it accomplishes my task. Thanks
